# Redirect a subdomain to backend server folder

Tags: haproxy

I have a wordpress installed on serverA 192.168.1.90/wordpress and a subdomain called mlb.example.com.

Using ACL in Haproxy, how do I redirect to a backend and still keep the subdomain name “mlb.example.com” rather than just showing the IP and folder in the browser.

Comment: Could you help me understand what you're trying to do? How is the subdomain involved? What HAProxy config have you tried (please add it to your question)?

Comment: rewrite mlb.example.com to http://192.168.1.90/wordpress/mlb/ and redirect to same 192.168.1.90 backend where the url in the browser should remain as mlb.example.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps adding reqrep to the backend:

```
acl host_server hdr(host) -i mlb.example.com

use_backend wordpresswebsite if host_server

backend wordpresswebsite

reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /mlb.example.com/(.*)     \1\ /wordpress/mlb/\2
```

Answer (score 0):

Route by ACLs.

acl host_wordpresswebsite hdr(host) -i wordpresswebsite.acme.com
[...]

use_backend wordpresswebsite if host_wordpresswebsite
[...]

backend wordpresswebsite
[...]

Comment: This just redirects to a backend server, but loses the original wordpresswebsite.acme.com in the browser heading.

Comment: Perhaps it requires a solution using reqrep.